I want to lookup values from pivot, if value does not found then use N using Pandas Dataframe
Input df

This is pivot I have.I want to lookup only zero value if there in above pivot and print N if value absent.
Expected df

In excel i am able to do comparison in these 2 df with sumif function
Check for zero value in above input pivot,If zero is found ,print it;if not ,print N to indicate the combination is nt available

Try this:
import pandas as pd
data = {'City': ['Honda', 'Honda', 'Access'], 'Bike Name': ['Mumbai', 'Delhi', 'Mumbai'], 'Number of': [10, 5, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.pivot(index='City', columns='Bike Name', values='Number of')


Bike Name  Delhi  Mumbai
City                    
Access       NaN     0.0
Honda        5.0    10.0

If you want to replace Nulls with 'N':
df.pivot(index='City', columns='Bike Name', values='Number of').fillna('N')


I want to just add N  in expected df.I dont want to replace if any value there

df.pivot_table(index='City', columns='Bike Name', values='Number of', fill_value='N')
